# Probability for equally likely

Tags: probability

When people attend a fundraiser, 40% of them donated the money. If three people John, Ray and David attend this month's fundraiser, what are the exact chances that just one of them will donate money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the three guys do not influence each other by talking (and are otherwise independent), the brute force approach is:

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{just 1 donation}) &= P(\text{1 donates}) \cdot P(\text{2 doesn't donate}) \cdot P(\text{3 doesn't donate})\\ 
                  &+ P(\text{1 doesn't donate}) \cdot P(\text{2 donates}) \cdot P(\text{3 doesn't donate}) \\
                  &+ P(\text{1 doesn't donate}) \cdot P(\text{2 doesn't donate}) \cdot P(\text{3 donates}) \\
                  &= 3 \cdot (P(\text{donates})  \cdot  P(\text{doesn't donate})^2) \\
                  &=  3  \cdot (0.4  \cdot  0.6^2) = 0.432
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You also need an assumption of identical distribution, i.e. they are equally likely to donate.

Comment: Number $X$ who donate has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=3,\,p=.4).$ Then $P(X=1) = 0.432$ from the formula for binomial PDF (or PMF). [This assumes independence and that each has $p=.4$ of donating.]